# How to post to multiple job boards from my job board - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

**What I like to do**

> I like to post job respectively to other `free job boards` upon checking a check_box when a job is created on my website.

**Graphical explanation**

This picture explains better what am hoping to achieve.

[image: post on multiple job boards]

**What I think of doing**

- Find a public API that can post on multiple websites, or;
- create `rails methods` that references those free job board's `new` action.

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming answers that can be answered in an authoritive way. It is not the place for recommendation or tips on general design of an application.

Comment: @max I envisage this will turn out to be this. I will take it down/edit off recommendations trend.